# Adding css to the front-end via plugin and variable

Tags: php, css, database, wordpress, plugins

Ok, I'm not really sure how to do this so maybe someone can help me out.

I am trying to create a function in my plugin that calls CSS to be used on the front-end of the site.  Sounds simple... but there's a catch.

Rather than calling a CSS file, I want to be able to call a PHP file that outputs the CSS styles from the database (plugin saved variable)..

For example... the standard method:

```
<?php

function register_style(){
    wp_register_style( 'front_stylesheet', plugins_url( '/css/custom.css', __FILE__ ) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'front_stylesheet' );
}
add_action( 'enqueue_scripts', 'register_style' );

?>
```

but I know I can't simply change "/css/rs.css" to the PHP file path. So how would I refer to that PHP file instead?

The PHP file is basically just a simple page that obtains the CSS styles from the database and outputs that content "without the STYLE tags because the tags are already echoed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the file as normal using the register_style method as you said and have the path as "/css/custom.php", and in the top of your `custom.php` file that generates the css, add:

```
header("Content-type: text/css");
```

This has to be the first line of the file with no whitespace before it.